# How can I simplify my state machine transitions?

Tags: c++, input, state

I currently have the following base class which I inherit from for my player states (e.g. Idle, Walking, Jumping).

```
struct PlayerState : std::enable_shared_from_this<PlayerState> {
    virtual ~PlayerState() {
    }

    virtual auto handle_input(const Input& input) -> std::shared_ptr<PlayerState> {
        return shared_from_this();
    }

    virtual auto update(AudioQueue& audio_queue, double dt) -> std::shared_ptr<PlayerState> {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};
```

`handle_input` and `update` can both be overridden to allow transistions between states, e.g.

```
struct IdleState : PlayerState {
    virtual auto handle_input(const Input& input) -> std::shared_ptr<PlayerState> override {
        bool jump = input.was_button_pressed(0);

        if(jump) {
            return std::make_shared<JumpingState>();
        }

        return shared_from_this();
    }
};
```

This works reasonably well and lets me write new states very quickly, however as the number of states is expanding I find I'm repeating myself a lot.

Take the example above, the code for handling jumping is duplicated in both the Idle and Walking states (as you can jump from either).

I'm sure there must be a better way to model these transitions but I just can't see it right now.

My first idea was to add an additional property to each state, e.g. `bool can_be_jumped_from` and then pushing the logic for jumping down into the base `PlayerState` class and ensure all inherited classes call the base `handle_input` method before their own. My concern here is that the number of these flags will grow every time I have a state that can be transitioned to from multiple places.

Is there an another simpler/tidier implementation I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

This is rather tricky question. The problem here are not flags `bool can_be_jumped_from` per se, but what actually lies behind it - FSM state transition. 
Number of state transitions required is not given by the *implementation* but rather by the *model* said FSM describes. Or in other words, `bool can_be_jumped_from` is not problem of shown implementation. Though you are very right about the maintenance issue.
A way to improve the ease of maintenance is to *abstract* more. Because code his its limits here, I would suggest employ some form of automation, may that be code generation frameworks (e.g. Visual Studio's [T4 temples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)), tools capable of modeling FSM, custom markup language (e.g. XML describing transitions and states) or any other way that helps both de-coupling implementation from the model and conveniently letting you focus on designing the model itself.
Another way is *optimizing* the model, reducing the number of FSM states and transitions required. I will not go into the details for FSM optimization as it would be out of scope this question - there is whole mathematics field behind. In any case, drawing (either by hand or by tool) the FSM should help understanding it substantially.

---

Not to leave you empty handed, I would suggest using a bit different and maybe more conventional implementation. Following wiki definition, [FSM is a quintuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine): set F of exit points (irrelevant for us), set of states S, the the entry point S0 (member of S), *delta *set of transitions (for convenience, by current state) and *sigma* the input alphabet, giving you a draft:

```
//handles the logic associated with the state through callbacks
class State//abstract
{
   virtual void OnEnter(State* previousState);
   virtual void OnStay();
   virtual void OnExit(State* nextState);
}

class IDecision { //sigma given implicitly by implementation
   virtual bool Decide(State state) = 0;//evaluates to true/false or 0..1 in case on non deterministic
}

//binds two states together and holds the decision logic
class ITransition { //deltaB
  State fromState;//key
  State toState;
  IDecision decision; 
}

//to-do optimize shared state, rest of logic
class FSM {
 std::vector<State> States;//S
 State entryPoint;//S0
 std::map<State, std::vector<Transition>> Transitions;
 void Update() { 
    //not actual syntax, cut short for brevity
    auto transfer = std::find_first_of(Transitions[currentState], [&t] -> { t.decision.Decide(currentState); });
    if(!transfer) currentState->OnStay(); 
    else Transfer(transfer);
 }

 void Transfer(ITransition transition)
 {
   transition.fromState().OnExit(currentState);
   transition.toState().OnEnter(currentState);
   currentState = transition.toState();
 }
 //...currentState, constructors, serialization, generic logic...
}
```

with similar setup (did not check any syntax!), you could implement reusable `Jump`ing:

```
class ShouldJumpDecision : public IDecision
{
  bool ShouldJump = false;
  ShouldJumpDecision(CommandManager manager) { 
    manager.Resgister<Input::Jump>([&] -> ShouldJump = true; ) 
  }
  virtual bool Decide(State state) override {
    return ShouldJump;
  }
}

class IddleState : public State {
  virtual void OnEnter(State* previousState) { animator.Play("IddleAnim") }
  virtual void OnExit(State* nextState)  { animator.Stop("IddleAnim") }
}

//PlayerFSM.xml parsed and automatically visualized and built by your engine tools
<Decisions>
  <Decision Name="ShouldJump">
    <Transitions>
      <Transition From="Iddle" To="Jump">
      <Transition From="Attacking" To="Jump">
    </Transitions>
  </Decision>
</Decisions>

//or created manually in code
fsm.AddTransition(iddle, ShouldJumpDecision, jump);
fsm.AddTransition(attacking, ShouldJumpDecision, jump);
```

If you are feeling generous, you can also implement something like the [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) for even more de-coupling.

Comment: Any comments typos/improving even further greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. When I first read it I was reluctant to make such sweeping changes and introduce what seemed like extra complexity. On reflection though this is considerably simpler and cleaner than any of the other avenues I was considering (the method in my question, CRTP, type traits, and a few others). I'll be trying to implement this sometime tomorrow.